# How to skip an \item in sub-enumerate level

Tags: lists, numbering, enumerate

I would like to skip an `\item` in a sub-enumerate level. More specifically, I want the output to look something like:

```
1. 
     a)
     b)
     e)
     f)
     etc.

2.
```

However, when I use `\addtocounter{enumi}` (within the first `\begin{enumerate}` `\end{enumerate}` block obviously), it increases the outer counter and I get:

```
1. 
     a)
     b)
     c)
     d)
     etc. (no skips!)

3.
```

So I am looking for a way to specify which counter to increase. Greatly appreciate the help!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There's a counter for each level:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item \mbox{}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item
    \item \addtocounter{enumii}{2}
    \item
    \item
  \end{enumerate}
  \item
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

In the default document class(es), `enumi` controls the enumeration at level 1, `enumii` for level 2, `enumiii` for level 3 and `enumiv` for level 4.

Answer (score 14):

You can refer to the current enumeration counter by `\@enumctr`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\skipitems}[1]{%
  \addtocounter{\@enumctr}{#1}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Outer
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Inner
    \item Inner again
    \skipitems{2}
    \item Inner again
    \skipitems{3}
    \item Inner again
  \end{enumerate}
  \item Outer again
  \skipitems{1}
  \item Let's end here
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hijacking with a follow-up question: I am using this idea but with \refstepcounter instead of \addtocounter.  It works, except that it conflicts with the \hyperref package.  That is, if I include \usepackage{hyperref} in the header it stops working with an error message about expecting a number (after the \skipitem).  Any advice on how to make this work with \hyperref?  Thanks.

Comment: @NealYoung Sorry, but I don't get it. Please open a fresh question with a minimal example.

Comment: Okay, here is fresh question, thanks: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/409432/conflict-between-hyperref-and-enumitem-packages-and-refstepcounter .  (By the way, the conflict is not with hyperref alone, it turns out to be a conflict with hyperref and enumitem combined.)