# How to number with indent?

Tags: formatting, numbering, indentation

I have a list of exercises that I want to answer using LaTeX. Is it possible to format it like this?

[image: Created with Microsoft Office Word 2013]

Is it possible to jump right from a) to c) in LaTeX? I have looked at the exercise-package, however it did not seem to be able to solve the indentation. The exercise was pushed below the exercise name.

Comment: This might help you: [How to skip an \item in sub-enumerate level](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101832/how-to-skip-an-item-in-sub-enumerate-level)

Comment: Or if the numbers are completely arbitrary, just use the optional argument of `\item`.  So `\item[a)]....` then `\item[c)]...`

Comment: @Thruston So I'll just name them manually? I started using LaTeX for the first time yesterday. We were told LaTeX is the standard when writing our Master's degree. However we get no information about how to use LaTeX. Do you know any good place to learn LaTeX quickly? And something that's up to date (PDF instead of DVI)?

Comment: If you are interested in learning LaTeX, have a look at this Thread: [What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-are-good-learning-resources-for-a-latex-beginner), it provides you useful links and several options.

Comment: I'd recommend getting a good book.  There are several excellent options mentioned in the answers to the questions linked above.

Comment: Kopka & Daly's *A Guide to LaTeX* got me through my dissertation with only a little help at the end to get things configured for my institution's nutty formatting requirements.