# conflict between hyperref and enumitem packages (and \refstepcounter)

Tags: cross-referencing, enumerate, enumitem, nesting

The solution outlined for each of the following two posts appears to conflict with the hyperref package.

1. [How to skip an \item in sub-enumerate level](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101832/how-to-skip-an-item-in-sub-enumerate-level)
2. [nested enumerated lists numbered for mathematical proofs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/409306/nested-enumerated-lists-numbered-for-mathematical-proofs)

Here is a MWE.  The desired output for the example is

```
1. Outer
2.1. This is line 2.1, in block 2. 
2.2. Inner again
3. Outer again
4. Let’s end here
```

This output is indeed produced by the LaTeX source below, but if I uncomment the \usepackage{hyperref} line in the header, LaTeX gives me an error just after the \skipitem command, as described in the inline comment below:

```
\documentclass{article}

% \usepackage{hyperref}
% if we uncomment the above line, we get an error as described below

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{steps}{enumerate}{9}
\setlist[steps]{itemindent=0pt}
\setlist[steps,1]{label=\arabic*.,ref=\arabic*}
\setlist[steps,2]{label=\arabic{stepsi}.\arabic*.,ref=\arabic{stepsi}.\arabic*}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\skipitem}{\refstepcounter{\@enumctr}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{steps}
\item Outer
  \skipitem
  % If we uncomment the \usepackage{hyperref} line in the header,
  % we get the following error after the \skipitem above
  % 
  % ./tmp.tex:20: Missing number, treated as zero.
  % <to be read again> 
  %   \c@0.0ptxcii 
  % l.20   \skipitem
  % \item[] \label{blockA}
  \label{blockA}\item[]
  \begin{steps}
  \item\label{lineB} This is line~\ref{lineB}, in block~\ref{blockA}.
  \item Inner again
  \end{steps}
\item Outer again
\item Let's end here
\end{steps}

\end{document}
```

Can someone help me work around this conflict, so I can use hyperref with this use of enumitems and refstepcounter?  Thanks.

(Note: smaller working examples are possible, but they give different error messages.  I'm hoping to get the current example working.)

Comment: Load `hyperref` **last**. NOT before `enumitem`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just load `hyperref` last. It should be last except for advertised exceptions, such as `cleveref`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{steps}{enumerate}{9}
\setlist[steps]{itemindent=0pt}
\setlist[steps,1]{label=\arabic*.,ref=\arabic*}
\setlist[steps,2]{label=\arabic{stepsi}.\arabic*.,ref=\arabic{stepsi}.\arabic*}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\skipitem}{\refstepcounter{\@enumctr}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{steps}
  \item Outer
  \skipitem
  \label{blockA}\item[]
  \begin{steps}
    \item\label{lineB} This is line~\ref{lineB}, in block~\ref{blockA}.
    \item Inner again
  \end{steps}
  \item Outer again
  \item Let's end here
\end{steps}
\end{document}
```

[image: links alive]

Note that you will probably need to delete generated files and compile cleanly to avoid getting errors on the initial runs after correcting your code.

Comment: And not just last, but after the declarations of the new list types. Wow, never would have figured that out.  Thanks.

Comment: @NealYoung Actually, I don't know if that's necessary or not. I just put it after everything list-related to be on the safe side.

Comment: FWIW I tried putting it immediately after the other \usepackage commands, and that did not work.

Comment: @NealYoung Thanks for the info. I had only checked that putting it after the lot worked, so I wasn't sure.