# Referencing character in Enumerate

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, enumerate

I have this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[\label=(X1)]
\item\label{i1} Hu
\item\label{i2} Pu
\end{enumerate}

Hello \ref{i1}.

\end{document}
```

In the PDF, I expected to see, "X1" as a hyperlink, but instead only "1" is coming:

[image]

How can I get "X1" automatically in the reference?

Comment: As mentioned on Page 1 of the [`enumerate` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/tools/enumerate.pdf): `\ref` only produces the counter value, not the whole label. So I think it is not possible to acheive your goal using the `enumerate` package. An alternative is to use the [`enumitem`](https://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package.

Comment: By the way, `[\label=(X1)]` only works by pure accident and you indeed fine warnings about ``Label `=' multiply defined``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at `enumitem` package!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}[label=(X\arabic*), ref=X\arabic*]
        \item\label{i1} Hu
        \item\label{i2} Pu
    \end{enumerate}

    Hello \ref{i1}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Minor suggestion: `hyperref` after `enumitem`. See, e.g., [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/409439/164314).

Comment: When I try, `\usepackage{enumitem}`, I get the error, `Undefined control sequence. \end{itemize}`.

Comment: OK, I guess found the problem, `\usepackage{paralist}`.

Comment: @pushpen.paul Yes, `enumitem` and `paralist` are incompatible. When using `enumitem`, to get paragraph-like lists, type something like `\begin{enumerate}[wide] ... \end{enumerate}`; to get inline lists, use the package option `inline` and then type something like `\begin{enumerate*} ... \end{enumerate*}`.