# Easy way to refer to local examples and equations without labeling them

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

Writing linguistic texts one often just refers to the preceeding or following example. Usually one does not need labels for this. I would like the (\mex{1}) references to behave more like references using labels and make them hyperlinked like \ref is in connection with hyperref. Is this possible? Right now, the makro `\mex` does not take the enumerated examples into account. So a, b, and c are not part of the referencing. I just write them down by hand. Is there a clever way to integrated reference to subexamples?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{langsci-gb4e}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mex}[1]{\the\numexpr\c@equation+#1\relax}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

This is some text referring to example (\mex{1}):
\ea
Test examples are always fun!
\z
As the existance of examples like (\mex{0}) shows.

There are even more complicated cases with enummerations of examples:
\eal
\ex This is the first example.
\ex This is the second example.
\zl
The example in (\mex{0}a) is similar to the one in (\mex{0}b).


\end{document}
```

Comment: The manual says: "In all cases, \label/\ref commands will do The Right Thing." I tried it out on your code, and indeed it does. Very impressive. What do you want the `\mex` command to do? Refer to last/current item in last/current list?

Comment: Yes, I am overwhelmed by \label/\ref and how good it works everyday. =:-) But I also love my hands and hate writing. (\mex{1}) refers to the next equation (\mex{2}) to the second forthcoming example and (\mex{0}) to the previous one. (\mex{-1}) to the penultimate one. I use labels when referring to an example from far away but locally I use `\mex`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a partial answer: I set a label for every example automatically. I guess I should include chapter information, if the chapter resets the example counter.

What I did not solve so far is the subexamples, a., b., c.:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{langsci-gb4e}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mex}[1]{\ref{ex-\the\numexpr\c@equation+#1}\relax}
\newcommand{\eaautolabel}{\label{ex-\the\numexpr\c@equation+1}}
\makeatother

\let\oldea\ea
\def\ea{\oldea\eaautolabel}

\let\oldeal\eal
\def\eal{\oldeal\eaautolabel}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

This is some text referring to example (\mex{1}):
\ea
Test examples are always fun!
\z
As the existance of examples like (\mex{0}) shows.

There are even more complicated cases with enummerations of examples:
\eal
\ex This is the first example.
\ex This is the second example.
\zl
The example in (\mex{0}a) is similar to the one in (\mex{0}b).


\end{document}
```

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101832/how-to-skip-an-item-in-sub-enumerate-level may help. `enumi`, `enumii`, `enumiii` and `enuniv` are the counters for enumerate environments in the standard classes. `gb4e`'s definition of the counter used by `\ex` needs to be known.

Comment: gb4e.sty, lines 214ff: `xnumi`, `xnumii`, etc. But `\thexnumi` etc are being set to typeset forms. Tricky.